# "Priority: cannot be blank" error while creating ticket

Tags: api, zendesk, zendesk-api

I am trying to create a request /api/v2/requests.json
below is my data:

```
{
request: {
    Priority: "Normal"
    comment: {body: "test"}
    from_mail: "pk@abccd.com"
    subject: "test"
    }
}
```

Auth token is correct but I am always getting the below error:

> responseJSON: {error: "RecordInvalid", description: "Record validation errors", details:
>   responseText: "{"error":"RecordInvalid","description":"Record validation errors","details":{"base":[{"description":"Priority: cannot be blank","error":"BlankValue","field_key":360012833834}]}}

Answer (score 0):

The documentation can be found [here](https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/support/requests#json-format).

Your mismatching fields:

- `Priority` vs `priority` with content `Normal` vs `normal`
- `from_mail` doesn't exist - `recipient` maybe?

I am not pretty sure if it's case sensitive, but that seems like an obvious mistake here.

Comment: I tried all combination of the case "P" vs "p" and so on. Also, if from_email doesn't exist then how was it working previously?